# mysql - Express JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to develop an Express.JS app and I am running into issues with MYSQL.

For example when I go to route '/items' I can do a mysql query using 'npm mysql' and then pass that data to the html page. However lets say I already have a page loaded, what would be the best way to do a new MYSQL query to refresh the data on the page?

Comment: which platform are you using on frontend?

Comment: Sounds like you need AJAX to me.

Comment: @BibekSubedi Im using Handlebars

Comment: @user964627go for Ajax

Comment: @BibekSubedi, that is where Im a bit lost. I would do an Ajax call to what? To a route in node?

Comment: @user964627 exactly, to a route in a node.